PHP - Call to undefined function PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\imagecreatefromstring()
I'm getting the above error code while using PHPspreadsheet but I can't figure out why imagecreatefromstring is mentioned. I'm not using this function. When checking the documentation I see the only mention is on line 1162 of the Reader\xls.php file.
I'm currently using the following functions:
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify
->load
->getSheetByName
->getHighestDataRow
->getCell
->getValue
->getHighestDataColumn
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex

Any idea why the function would be called?
Edit for stack trace:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\imagecreatefromstring() in C:\ProgramData\EDI\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls.php:1162
Stack trace:
#0 C:\ProgramData\EDI\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\BaseReader.php(182): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls->loadSpreadsheetFromFile('\\\\Nas\\edi\\TED_B...')
#1 \\192.168.0.222\EDI\ROUTES\TedBakerRetailStreamliner.php(21): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\BaseReader->load('\\\\Nas\\edi\\TED_B...')
#2 C:\ProgramData\EDI\edidaemon.php(97): TedBakerRetailStreamliner(Array)
#3 C:\ProgramData\EDI\edidaemon.php(21): processedi()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\ProgramData\EDI\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls.php on line 1162


Doesn't the error tell you how this method gets called?

Hi, my bad I forgot to include the stack trace. It's in the post now.

It looks like you don't have the gd extension enabled.

Hi I will try this and check as solved. Thanks for your help in any case.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php.
